South Africa - are multiple entries possible with the online temporary sojourn visa?
I'm a Slovak citizen and I'm planning a trip a round trip starting from South Africa to Botswana and Zimbabwe. I'm currently filling out an eVisa application form. I am wondering if the eVisa DHA-eP1 provides an option of multiple entries (I need to enter twice - upon arrival from Europe and when returning from Zimbabwe). Surprisingly, I have not found a conclusive answer to this question, and the online application allows to fill in data for only one entry. Thanks for any hints.

Logically then, if the online system doesn’t offer a multiple entry option, you have to complete another application for  your return from Zimbabwe.

Thank you for your help with searching for the information. Unfortunately, no option of entering the information about multiple entry was offered in the online application. I contacted the Department of Home Affairs and their response was as follows:
"Kindly note that you will have to visit the South African Embassy in your country of residence to consult with the Immigrations Office, and communicate your intention for multiple entry. They will assist further."
Therefore, I submitted my visa application at the embassy of my country of residence, which offers the option of multiple entry visa.

Possibly at the end of the application you will be offered the option to add a second visit.
Unfortunatly the text seems to be cut off mid sentence.

Sources:

Department of Home Affairs - ePermits - Frequently asked Questions:


Can I obtain a multiple-entry eVisa?

'Yes. This is determined during the ad'


(text seems to be cut off here)
